# Execute two external programs in UWP program

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to execute two external programs in my UWP program (using c#)

Now, I use `FullTrustProcessLanucher.LanuchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync(`) to execute one but I don't know how to add another.

Could you please help me to do this problem, if have the better solve way, please feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Create one app as full trust process. The app will then open the two external programs